# Silverstripe 3.5 - How to query for specific columns and return an array

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to do a select all to get three columns from a single table and then simply use the result as an array. Without the expense of a loop.

I have tried this using the ORM method:

```
DataObject::get('City')->sort('Name ASC')->toNestedArray();
```

This gives me an array perfectly. But I can't see a way to only return the columns I want. It returns all columns. This is a problem because I am json encoding this array and the packet is 3 times as big as it needs to be due to this.

So I tried this using SQLQuery instead:

```
DB::query('SELECT "ID","Name","ParentID" FROM "City"');
```

Now this allows me to select the three fields, but as far as I can tell, there is no method to return this query as an array like toNestedArray()

Searched high and low but nothing fits. Any ideas?

Edit: Should have mentioned I have tried setQueriedColumns() sorry. This doesn't seem to be intended for what I am doing here.

```
$cities = AspireCity::get()->sort(['Name' =>  'ASC'])->setQueriedColumns(['ID', 'Name']);
Debug::dump($cities->toNestedArray());
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ClassName] => City
            [LastEdited] => 2017-09-26 11:14:16
            [Name] => Acacia Bay
            [ID] => 70
            [RecordClassName] => City
            [Created] => 
            [ParentID] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ClassName] => City
            [LastEdited] => 2017-09-26 11:14:16
            [Name] => Ahaura
            [ID] => 71
            [RecordClassName] => City
            [Created] => 
            [ParentID] => 9
        )
```

Comment: Checkout http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns

Comment: Thank you. I did try that but doesn't seem to work as intended. See the edit to my question for detail. Perhaps toNestedArray() ignores it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when using the ORM, the dataobject system fields are always output. These are ClassName, LastEdited, ID, Created. `setQueriedColumns` then allows you to choose the fields which you have added to your DataObject Model. If you only want the fields ID, Name, ParentID you will need to use sql queries as you have done in your answer below.

Comment: Didn't silverstripe lazy load the data of a DataObject if its not present so calling toNestedArray would definately fire loading of all values per iteration, but can't remember would calling only the attributes that were part of the query cause loading the rest of the missing DO data also.

Comment: I'm refering to this: http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/source-class-DataObject.html#2424 more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided that this was a case a of over-reliance on existing SS helper methods. While toNestedArray() is very handy, my focus on it was to based primarily on thinking I can avoid a loop by using it. When in reality, the method is of course a loop. So really my concern is unfounded.

The most important goal was reducing the dataset at the time of query. So the solution simply focuses on that.

```
// Inject the default country/city/suburb data as vars so they can be easily filtered.
$location['countries'] = DB::query('SELECT "ID","Description" FROM "Country" ORDER BY "ID" ASC'); 
$location['cities'] = DB::query('SELECT "ID","Name","ParentID" FROM "City" ORDER BY "Name" ASC'); 
$location['suburbs'] = DB::query('SELECT "ID","Name","ParentID" FROM "Suburb" ORDER BY "Name" ASC');

$masterLocationArray = [];
foreach($location as $key => $data) {
    $locationArray = [];
    foreach($data as $item) {
        $locationArray[] = $item;
    }
    $masterLocationArray[$key] = $locationArray;
}

// $masterLocationArray is our filtered, tidy array. Do stuff with it
```

Comment: I suggest you use `SQLSelect` over raw DB queries. It'll ensure compatibility with the different RDBMs and reduce the risk of injection attacks.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API Docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/en/3.6/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns), `setQueriedColumns()` is your friend:

From your question I assume the DataObject you want to query is called `City`, so we need this to get all cities out of the database:

```
City::get();
```

This returns a `DataList` and queries the database when you need it. Up to now, your DB doesn't know anything that you want some data from it. So let's refine it, sort it by "Name" ASC. I like the array syntax much more, IMHO it's easier to read, and if you need to sort against a second row, just add it to the array:

```
City::get()
    ->sort(['Name' =>  'ASC']);
```

Now you wanted, for some reasons, just some columns back. As I don't know what database fields your `City` DataObject has, I assume you just want 'Name' and 'ZIP':

```
City::get()
    ->sort(['Name' =>  'ASC'])
    ->setQueriedColumns(['Name', 'ZIP']);
```

This limits the queried columns and you can add `toNestedArray()` to get the data out as a pure vintage array. This might be useful to pass the data to an API, but maybe it's better to leave the objects and use City specific logic in your code.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I looked at setQueriedCoumns. I figured it was not relevant. Doesn't seem to serve this purpose

    $cities = City::get()->sort(['Name' =>  'ASC'])->setQueriedColumns(['ID', 'Name']);
        Debug::dump($cities->toNestedArray());

Outputs all fields in the table

Comment: you can see the generated query by adding `->sql()` to the DataList. My guess is, that it first reduces the query, but when your run `toNestedArray()` laster it fetches the other columns.

Comment: Na I actually tested a loop over the List without using toNestedArray(), All fields were there. Not sure why setQueriedColumns doesn't seem to do what it says. In my case it doesn't.

Comment: Did you check the generated SQL query? DataObject might lazyload the other fields later on when they're needed